# Elastic fleet server, authenticate with service account token 401

Tags: elasticsearch

I am following the [guides here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/service-accounts.html) to create a token for the `elastic/fleet-server` service account.

I successfully created the token with the command:

```
bin/elasticsearch-service-tokens create elastic/fleet-server fleet-token
```

and try to execute the request `http://localhost:9200/_security/_authenticate` with the bearer authorization. I receive the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "security_exception",
                "reason": "failed to authenticate service account [elastic/fleet-server] with token name [fleet-token]",
                "header": {
                    "WWW-Authenticate": [
                        "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"",
                        "ApiKey"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "security_exception",
        "reason": "failed to authenticate service account [elastic/fleet-server] with token name [fleet-token]",
        "header": {
            "WWW-Authenticate": [
                "Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\"",
                "ApiKey"
            ]
        }
    },
    "status": 401
}
```

It clearly understands the token because it provides the token name in the error message. The permissions for that service account are below:

```
"elastic/fleet-server" : {
    "role_descriptor" : {
      "cluster" : [
        "monitor",
        "manage_own_api_key"
      ],
      "indices" : [
        {
          "names" : [
            "logs-*",
            "metrics-*",
            "traces-*",
            "synthetics-*",
            ".logs-endpoint.diagnostic.collection-*",
            ".logs-endpoint.action.responses-*"
          ],
          "privileges" : [
            "write",
            "create_index",
            "auto_configure"
          ],
          "allow_restricted_indices" : false
        },
        {
          "names" : [
            ".fleet-*"
          ],
          "privileges" : [
            "read",
            "write",
            "monitor",
            "create_index",
            "auto_configure",
            "maintenance"
          ],
          "allow_restricted_indices" : false
        }
      ],
      "applications" : [
        {
          "application" : "kibana-*",
          "privileges" : [
            "reserved_fleet-setup"
          ],
          "resources" : [
            "*"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "run_as" : [ ],
      "metadata" : { },
      "transient_metadata" : {
        "enabled" : true
      }
    }
  }
```

I am running Elastic/Kibana/Elastic-Agent with Docker, version 7.17.6.

The documentation seems fairly straight forward so not sure where to go from here. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact challenge
I resolved it by restarting elasticsearch as well as kibana after generating the service token.

My Environment:
Both Kibana and Elastic Search were running on Debian VM